# Can I pass arguments into GWT Module constructor?

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection, gwt-gin

I have the following GWT module:

```
public class FizzModule implements EntryPoint {
    private Buzz buzz;

    public FizzModule() {
        this(null);
    }

    public FizzModule(Buzz bz) {
        super();

        setBuzz(bz);
    }

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // ...etc.
    }
}
```

I would like to "inject" `FizzModule` with a `Buzz` instance. However, all of the code examples I see for GWT modules do not use constructors. Instead, they bootstrap the DI mechanism (typically either ClientFactory or GIN) from inside the `onModuleLoad()` method. Is this something that GWT forces, or can I somehow inject my module before it loads to the client-side? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT instantiates your module using its zero-arg constructor, always.

(technically, I think it uses `GWT.create()` so you could use deferred binding rules, but that wouldn't change anything re. how its instantiated)

BTW, where would the `Buzz` instance come from?

Answer (score 0):

You could add parameters to the URL and use PlaceController. Then get those values on module load.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    SimplePanel mainPanel = new SimplePanel();
    EventBus eventBus = GWT.creat(EventBus.class);
    // Start ActivityManager for the main widget with ActivityMapper
    ActivityManager activityManager = new ActivityManager(injector.getActivityMapper(),
            eventBus);
    activityManager.setDisplay(mainPanel);
    RootPanel.get().add(mainPanel);

    // Start PlaceHistoryHandler with our PlaceHistoryMapper
    AppPlaceHistoryMapper contentHistoryMapper = GWT.create(AppPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
    PlaceHistoryHandler historyHandler = new PlaceHistoryHandler(contentHistoryMapper);
    PlaceController placeController = new PlaceController(eventBus)
    historyHandler.register(placeController, injector.getEventBus(), new MainPlace());

    // Goes to the place represented on URL else default place
    historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();
    if(placeController.getWhere() instanceof MainPlace) {
        (MainPlace).getFoo();
    }
}

public class MainPlace extends Place {

    private String foo;

    public MainPlace(String token) {
        String foo = token;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public static class Tokenizer implements PlaceTokenizer<MainPlace> {

        @Override
        public MainPlace getPlace(String token) {
            return new MainPlace(token);
        }

        @Override
        public String getToken(MainPlace place) {
            return place.getFoo();
        }
    }
}
```